# Spring-AOP Return value of Aspect @AfterReturn is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, aspect

```
@AfterReturning(value = "anyPublicMethod() && applyPrivacy()", returning = "result")
public Object afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
 return someService.createNewObjectWithHelpOfResult(result);
}
```

My intention was to fill some null values in result fields. So in method `createNewObjectWithHelpOfResult` I'm creating a new Object and setting only the required values. But return value is not reflecting after `afterReturning` method is finished. But if I do mutations on `result`. They're very well reflected after aspect @AfterReturning method ends, but I want the return value to be used? Is this not possible? I'll have to do mutation only?

Comment: afterreturning doesn't use the return value of the method, the method should be `void`. If you want to change the return value you need an `@Around` advice.

Comment: Please be polite enough to react to comments and answers, either accepting and upvoting them or writing comments if there is anything you do not understand or disagree with. This question is still listed as unaccepted, even though it has a correct answer. Other people looking for open questions in order to help are going to run into this one, only to find out after reading that here is nothing to be done anymore.

Answer (score 0):

What *@M.Deinum* explained, is documented in the [Spring manual, section "After Returning Advice"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-advice-after-returning). The end of the section reads:

> Please note that it is **not** possible to return a totally different reference when using after returning advice.

Therefore, you cannot just make your `@AfterReturning` advice have a return type other than `void` and hope it will magically return something. As the advice type name implies, all 3 types of `@After*` advices run ***after*** the method has returned already. There is nothing you can do to change the result (except for altering internal state of an object instance). You can merely read (and e.g. log) it.

The solution, like *@M.Deinum* said, is an `@Around` advice, see also again the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice).

It is generally a good idea to at least study the manual and learn some basics or take a look at examples before asking questions in public. I am sure you did not find any valid example for an `@After*` advice with non-void return type.

Answer (score 0):

I am using @AfterReturning on the methods whose return type is String but instead of String I am getting null as result
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.example.demo.aop.business.*.*(..))", returning = "result")
public void afterA(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {

```
    log.info("After method {} returned with value {}", joinPoint, result);

}
```

O/P -  After method execution(void com.example.demo.aop.business.Business2.disp()) returned with value null